# Gif image is not working in nexus one device

Tags: android, animated-gif

I am using gif image in my application. It is not working in nexus one device.

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layout, null);
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView view.findViewById(R.id.img_view_id);
GifAnimationDrawable big = new GifAnimationDrawable(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.flights_loading_loader));

big.setOneShot(false);
imageView.setImageDrawable(big);
big.setVisible(true, true);
mProgressDialog.setContentView(view);
```

Comment: Please explain completely and precisely what "it is not working" means.

Comment: I have customized gif-blink image in android alert dialog view. i have called gif image below line com.travel.animationdrawable.GifAnimationDrawable big = new com.travel.animationdrawable.GifAnimationDrawable(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.flights_loading_loader)); But is not blink in nexus one device.

Comment: Nexus _One_? There were people actually using that device in 2015?